# How to give the response if the user give unknow intent name in alexa

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I created PHP webhook and used https service to call the intent response,
but when user says unknow intent name it must give the response sorry.

but I didn't get the response.

My code

```
if(intent->name="name of intent") {
   echo response
}
else if(intent->name="name of intent") {
   echo response
}
else{
   echo response
}
```

But I'm not getting into else part

Comment: Add the request JSON generated and some actual code to look upon.

Comment: if i use "WHAT WAS THAT" then it is going to else part but when i call "xyz" it is not showing any response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code:

```
if(intent->name="name of intent") {
   echo response
}
else if(intent->name="name of intent") {
   echo response
}
else{
   echo response
}
```

you are using "=" instead of "==" and hence it never goes to else part.

edited code:

```
if(intent->name=="name of intent") {
   echo response
}
else if(intent->name=="name of intent") {
   echo response
}
else{
   echo response
}
```